# AWS Sagemaker Pytorch does not run properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am currently trying to train a model using pytorch on AWS Sagemaker but can't get it to run properly. My main question now is: Is there some workflow step I'm missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I managed to get the code running on colab or on a local machine for example but not on sagemaker.

In short the program should: Setup a pytorch model, load the train data from a file system and perform train epochs.

For this, I am trying the following:
The code files (dataloaders/help functions etc) with the "entry point" are stored at Sagemaker Studio in the folder "code".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqHi3.png)

The train files are stored in a s3 bucket and are transfered in "file mode".

I then call the estimator in a python notebook as this:

```
estimator = PyTorch(entry_point='entry.py',
                    role=role,
                    py_version='py3',
                    source_dir = "code",
                    output_path = "s3://XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXX",
                    framework_version='1.3.1',
                    instance_count=1,
                    instance_type='ml.g4dn.2xlarge',
                    hyperparameters={
                        'epochs': 5,
                        'backend': 'gloo'
                    })

inputs = "s3://XXXXX/XXXXX"
estimator.fit({'training': inputs})
```

In the output I can see, that the train instance is prepared and the data is downloaded but then the problem arises:

For some reason the program jumps right into the train method. The outputs of the first steps which should take place before a train epoch, Network whitening for example, are shown after or during the train step. After one train epoch the program freezes without any error message until I manually stop the instance.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your script gets stuck after one epoch.
There's no error messages to review, nor the code itself.
I suggest to try and troubleshoot this in a fast manner using [SageMaker Local mode](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html?highlight=local#local-mode) (e.g., `instance_type='local_gpu'`). This will allow you to retry different configurations in seconds instead of minutes. And potentially [remote debug](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/tree/main/tensorflow_script_mode_debug_local_training) it.

Note: SageMaker local requires docker support, so you'll need to run this either on your laptop, or on a SageMaker notebook instance like 'ml.g4dn.2xlarge', but not on a SageMaker Studio instance). And potentially [remote debug](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/tree/main/tensorflow_script_mode_debug_local_training) it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gili,

it turned out, that the script was not stuck and actually running.  For some reason the train logs in the console or at CloudWatch appear only after the training job is completed, which i still don't understand. But the code runs as it should.
Thanks again.